# How does wager in dota2 works

Tags: dota-2

I got a last compendium, it seems that when I wager my coins to a game and lose, I don't lose any coins.

What is the point then? Why would someone not wager every coin they have every game, why is there even the option?

Comment: The result is the same when winning, no coin added

Comment: I see my coins added and substracted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official description is:
Coin Wagering allows players to earn coins by predicting their match victories.
Before a match begins, players place a Wager of Compendium Coins. When the match begins, the Wagers from all players are added together, minus 5%, to form the total Coin Pool.
After the battle, each player on the victorious team wins a percentage of the Coin Pool based on their Wager compared to the rest of their team.

So, atleast one player from both teams need to wager the coins for winnings/loss.
I am going to play today, Will keep this updated.

Also, now we have a chance to win bonus coins and cap of 5% is removed from total winnnings.

Comment: Yes they totally don't mention that if only players in 1 team wager coins, nobody wins nor lose anything. The thing only works if both teams are in.

Comment: Right, at first I was surprised/confused when i added coins and nobody added. then at the end what happened to my coins.
Consequently I won a match and I got reward, they just need to add more details about this system. That's all.

Comment: Also there seems to be a cap of double your wager. Had a game where I bet 100 vs 500 coin and only won 190.